# Constructor Oput Not Coming

Tags: java, bluej

```
class Constr
{
    int a;

    Constr()
    {
        int a=5;;
    }

    public void sd()
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main()
    {       
        Constr obj=new Constr();
        obj.sd();       
    }
}
```

When we run this code we get an output: `{ 0 }`

Comment: `int a=5;;`  you reinitialize the variable `a` in the contructor. change the line to `a=5;`. look up member variable and their scope

Comment: Please avoid adding things like "reply fast", it usually won't have the desired effect.

Comment: Please put more effort into your formatting, punctuation and spelling, writing such posts is disrespectful for the readers.

Answer (score 1):

> The default value of instance variable of an int primitive is set to 0
>   by default.

Now since in your Constructor you are redeclaring the variable `a` instead of assigning the value to the instance variable, you are not getting your desired output (i.e. value of variable a should be set to 0).

Instead, try this :

```
 class Constr {
  int a;
  Constr() {
   a = 5; // Assigning the value to the instance variable.

  }

  public void sd() {
   System.out.println(a);
  }

  public static void main() {

   Constr obj = new Constr();
   obj.sd();

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
Constr(){
    int a=5;  
}
```

you create a new variable instead of assigning 5 to the one you created outside. Remove the declaration, leaving just `a=5`.

Answer (score 0):

Global variable and local variable is different. In class, not initialize "a" is global and in constructor "a" is local variable. If you need to show the local variable value 5 . Modified the following.

class Constr
{
    int a;

```
Constr()
{
    int a=5;
    this.a = a;
}

public void sd()
{
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static void main()
{       
    Constr obj=new Constr();
    obj.sd();       
}
```

}

Comment: It's not global. I guess what you meant by Global as  'Instance variable'. Java doesn't support global variable :).

Comment: i mean global var is class own and local var is method or constructor own var.